# Contar la cantidad de veces que se repite un dato en una columna específica de un .csv con Numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Quisiera saber cómo puedo contar la cantidad de veces que se repite un dato en una columna específica de un archivo csv con Numpy, sin ocupar pandas.
A modo de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo ese archivo csv, lo primero que hice fue leer el archivo:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

#Leer el archivo CSV
with open('archivo.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f, delimeter=";"))
    data = np.array(data)
```

Luego definí la variable cod_pers:

```
cod_pers = '2086638'
```

Y luego intenté contar la cantidad de veces que se repite ese cod_pers en la columna correspondiente a cod_pers del csv, para ello intenté:

```
result= (data == cod_pers).sum()
```

Lo cual esperaba que me diera como resultado el valor 5, pero me dio 0.

Por favor su ayuda!!

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser con numpy?

Comment: si, no tengo permitido usar pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código lee un .csv creando un arreglo cuyas columnas tienen nombres extraidos del header del mismo .csv.

Para no tener que tipear los datos de la imagen, use un .csv que tenía por ahí:

```
ano,nombre,sexo,n
2000,Juan,m,10
2000,Maria,f,3
2001,Juan,m,5
2001,Maria,f,6
```

y deseo contar las personas con sexo 'm':

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('nac.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True, encoding="UTF-8")
print(sum(data['sexo'] == 'm'))
```

Puedes leer directamente el .csv usando `genfromtxt`. Es forzoso incluir `encoding=` para obtener los textos convertidos a unicode.

Como las columnas tienen nombres, `data['sexo']` se refiere a la tercera columna.

Obvio, debes reemplazar los nombres de este ejemplo con los que usas en tu .csv.

Comment: Me da error el print(sum(data['sexo'] == 'm')), porque me lo toma como boolean al hacer el ==

Comment: @IgnacioZumelzu. Raro. En casos así, agrega un `print(data)` a ver que es lo que está leyendo. ¿Problemas de enconding, tal vez?

Comment: Lo estaba colocando mal yo, ahí si me sirvió, graciaas