# Contar la cantidad de registros de un CSV con una condición de últimos 15 días - numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy

tengo la siguiente consulta para realizar, cabe destacar que no tengo permitido utilizar la librería de pandas, por ello busco una solución con NumPy.

Tengo como archivo CSV:

#Se modifica el 29/02 por el 28/02

```
cod_pers,cod_enti,cod_tipo_docu_deud,cod_cond_deud,cod_mone,fec_venc
    2317422,45214,16,4,1,06/04/2022
    1024726942,30538,16,1,1,05/04/2022
    2392115,71758,16,4,1,17/02/2022
    2086638,592,6,1,1,13/09/2018
    2086638,975,6,1,1,13/11/2020
```

Y lo que busco realizar con el es contar la cantidad de registros que están en el rango de los últimos 15 días contando desde hoy (06/04/2022) según `fec_venc`.

Por lo que espero como respuesta el número `2`, ya que los campos `06/04/2022`y `05/04/2022` de `fec_venc` están dentro de **hoy(06/04/2022)-15 días**

Para ello tengo el código:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from time import strftime
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

#Leer el archivo CSV
data = np.genfromtxt(r'datos.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True, encoding="UTF-8")

#definición días
hoy = date.today()
dia_hoy = date.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
ayer = hoy - timedelta(days=15)
dias_antes = ayer.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

#cod_pers en los últimos 15 días
resultado = sum(data['cod_pers'][data['fec_venc'] > dias_antes])

print(resultado)
```

Pero me entrega el valor de `2392115`, no el número `2` como espero.
Por favor su ayuda para entender mejor el error de este problema u otra forma de poder obtener el resultado que espero con NumPy. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @Juan Carlos Gonzalez Quesada la próxima vez que hagas una edición, _no toques el código_, ya que se debe mantener la intención original del autor de la pregunta o respuesta. Debe ser el OP quien modifique su pregunta (en este caso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visto que no se puede usar la librería `pandas` lo que usaremos será `numpy` y el siguiente código:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from time import strftime
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

#Leer el archivo CSV
data = np.genfromtxt(r'datos.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True, encoding="UTF-8")

#definición días
hoy = date.today()
dia_hoy = date.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
ayer = hoy - timedelta(days=15)
dias_antes = ayer.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

#Dia que debemos superar
dias_antes = datetime.strptime(dias_antes, "%d/%m/%Y")
print("Debemos superar", dias_antes, type(dias_antes))

#De esta forma, convertimos el string "fec_encv" a datetime 
valores_en_fecha = []
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    aux = datetime.strptime(data[i][5], "%d/%m/%Y")
    valores_en_fecha.append(aux)

#Guardamos en resultado sólo aquellos valores que sean después del "dia_de_ayer"
resultado = []
for i in range(0, len(valores_en_fecha)):
    if(valores_en_fecha[i] > dias_antes):
        resultado.append(data[i])
        

print(resultado)
```

Que nos dará como salida:

```
Debemos superar 23/03/2022
[(2317422, 45214, 16, 4, 1, '06/04/2022'), (1024726942, 30538, 16, 1, 1, '05/04/2022')]
```

Si queremos obtener además el número de valores que nos devuelve, habría que añadir al final la siguiente línea:

```
print("El número de filas es ", len(resultado))
>> El número de filas es 2
```

Comment: Holaa @Juan Carlos Gonzalez Quesada muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
Al ejecutar el siguiente código me entrega un error de ValueError: day is out of range for month

Comment: Ah, si. Ahora lo voy a poner en el comentario. El problema es que no existe el 29 de febrero (Aunque sea año bisiesto, no está contemplado en Python)

Comment: Toda la razón, ahí modifiqué el código y cambié el día 29/02/2022 a 17/02/2022 y ahora me entrega un error de TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

Comment: Has copiado el código tal cual?

Comment: Así es, tal cual

Comment: Perdona, se me olvidó añadir una lína, ya la tienes puesta. Es la que viene depués de ```#Dia que debemos superar`` Prueba ahora y me dices

Comment: Ahora si lo entrega perfecto. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Nada @Nube Cualquier cosa dime ;)

Comment: Una pregunta solamente de curioso, en caso de yo querer obtener el número la cantidad de resultados que me entrega, como en este caso debería ser 2, tendría que agregarle alguna función??

Comment: Te lo añado en el código también

Comment: Me respondo solo, puedo realizar eso con np.count_nonzero(resultado)

Comment: Es mejor la opción que te puse, devover el tamaño del array con ```len()```

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Nadaaa. Lo que necesites

Comment: por favor, podrias explicar esta afirmacion "PARA PYTHON NO EXISTE EL DÍA 29 DE FEBRERO"... creo que ya hace mas de 30 años que ningun lenguaje tiene problemas con las fechas...

Comment: Claro que python computa correctamente el día 29 de febrero, pero sólo si el año es bisiesto. En los años no bisiestos el 29 de febrero no existe. **Y 2022 no es bisiesto**.

Comment: Correcto. Estaba en que este año es bisiesto. Efectivamente, desde hace tiempo, los le. Guajes de programación aceptan los años bisiestos. Buen apunte

Comment: No obstante, no afecta a la resolución del problema. Por lo que si en vez de 2022 pones el 29 de febrero de 2020 o del 2024, el programa irá perfecto también.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo es que la forma de leer los datos, es un poco incorrecta.
Si printeas lo que te da data, tiene este aspecto:

```
[(   2317422, 45214, 16, 4, 1, '06/04/2022')
 (1024726942, 30538, 16, 1, 1, '05/04/2022')
 (   2392115, 71758, 16, 4, 1, '29/02/2022')
 (   2086638,   592,  6, 1, 1, '13/09/2018')
 (   2086638,   975,  6, 1, 1, '13/11/2020')]
```

Por lo que, te está devolviendo el primer valor de la tercera fila.
La mejor forma de leer un csv y poder acceder a todas las columnas sin problema, sería la siguiente:

```
data = pd.read_csv("datos.csv")
```

Que te devuelve como resultado un dataFrame que es mucho más legible y con el que se puede trabajar mejor:

```
     cod_pers  cod_enti  cod_tipo_docu_deud  cod_cond_deud  cod_mone    fec_venc
0     2317422     45214                  16              4         1  06/04/2022
1  1024726942     30538                  16              1         1  05/04/2022
2     2392115     71758                  16              4         1  29/02/2022
3     2086638       592                   6              1         1  13/09/2018
4     2086638       975                   6              1         1  13/11/2020
```

Finalmente, tu código con las modificaciones sería el siguiente:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import strftime

import pandas as pd

#Leer el archivo CSV
data = pd.read_csv("datos.csv")
print(data)

#definición días
hoy = datetime.today()
print("El dia de hoy", hoy)

#El día hace 15 días
ayer = hoy - timedelta(days=15)
print("El dia de ayer", ayer)

#Para poder comparar de forma correcta con ayer (Debido a que es de tipo datatime)
for i in range(0, len(data["fec_venc"])):
    data["fec_venc"][i] = datetime.strptime(data["fec_venc"][i], '%d/%m/%Y')

#cod_pers en los últimos 15 días
#Obtenemos del dataFrame los valores que cumplan que la fecha es superior a hace 15 días
resultado = data[data["fec_venc"] > ayer]

print("El numero de filas desde hace 15 días es ", len(resultado), " y lo valores son\n", resultado)

#Si quieres filtar solo opor cod_pers
print("Los Cod_pers son\n", resultado["cod_pers"])
```

Espero que te sirva, cualquier duda. Dímelo!

Comment: El OP menciono [en su primera pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/526270/contar-la-cantidad-de-veces-que-se-repite-un-dato-en-una-columna-espec%c3%adfica-de-u) que no puede usar Pandas. Si esta es la misma tarea, entonces eso no ha cambiado. Aun así es bueno ver una alternativa usando Pandas.

Comment: De acuerdo. Curioso que revises eso y no se eche un cable. Pero gracias por el apunte, ya está resuelto sin usar la librería PANDA

Comment: Era más que me pareció reconocer el código y que el dueño de dicho código no podía usar pandas y decidí revisar las preguntas del OP hasta encontrar la pregunta donde lo menciona. Y de nada c: